# nasm: how to pad the beginning of the string such that it ends right at an alignment boundary

Tags: assembly, nasm

I cannot figure out how to pad the beginning of the string such that it ends right at an alignment boundary:

```
%macro string 1
_unaligned:
; some preprocesor expression comes here
    db %1
_aligned:
%endmacro
```

After several hours of trying different solutions, I still don't have any. Can anybody help, please?

EDIT:

This is the real example how it should work (for 32bit code):

```
%define LAST 0

%macro xword 2
%strlen len %1
                ; pad - some preprocassor magic comes here
                db %1
NAME__%2        db len
LINK__%2        dd LAST ; must be aligned !!!
CODE__%2        dd code
PAR__%2
%define LAST PAR__%2
%endmacro
```

Usage:

xword 'TEST',test01

creates structure (for example $ = 0x0001):

```
0x0001  
0x0002  
0x0003  db 'T'
0x0004  db 'E'
0x0005  db 'S'
0x0006  db 'T'
0x0007  db 4
0x0008  dd 0    ; LAST (must be ALIGNED)
0x000C  dd code
```

There must be no more padding than necessary, as it is necessary to save as much memory as possible.

Comment: Can't you just add a `align 16, db 0` (or whatever granularity you want) before the `_aligned` line?

Comment: @Michael I am not really sure what OP wants.  I guess he wants to pad the beginning of the string such that it ends right at an alignment boundary?

Comment: @Michael No, I need that there is no gap between the string and the following data, and that the following data starts at an aligned address.

Comment: @fuz yes, this is correct.

Comment: @iooo Please update your question to clarify this.  You can press [edit] to edit your question at any time.

Comment: @fuz i did it. thank you.

Comment: Is the operand to this macro always going to be a single string? It might be useful if you could give an example of how the macro is used and what the desired result is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work, though it's suboptimal as it may add more padding than necessary in some cases:

```
%macro string 1
   %strlen numchars %1
   align 4, db 0
   times (4-numchars)&3 db 0
   db %1
   %%_aligned:   
%endmacro
```

Replace 4 by whatever alignment you want (and the 3 with your alignment minus 1).

---

**Edit:** Here's another version that should avoid adding more padding than necessary:

```
%macro string 1
   %strlen %%numchars %1
   %%loc equ ($-$$)
   times (4-(%%loc+%%numchars))&3 db 0
   db %1
   %%_aligned:   
%endmacro
```

This version assumes that the start of all sections in which you use this macros are aligned on *at least* the same power of 2 that you want to align the data on.

Comment: This is about what I thought of writing, but it doesn't extend to the usual idioms like `string "foo", 10, 13, 0` if that is desired by OP.  Also, `numchars` should be made macro-local.

Comment: @fuz: When I tested this with multiple invocations, nasm didn't seem to mind `numchars` not being explicitly macro-local. `_aligned` needs to be though.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't mind, but it also generates a symbol `numchars`, polluting the namespace.

Comment: @Michael i updated the question by adding a real example how it should work.